# How to access an object entry by a specific depth?

Tags: javascript, object, recursion

Is there any way in Javascript to instantly access an object value with a specific depth?

There is an example:

```
{
  "level": {
    "value": "one",
    "level": {
      "value": "two",
      "level": {
        "value": "three",
        "level": {
          "value": "four",
          "level": {
            "value": "five"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can do that with recursion. Check the first object value `level` and if it exists then go to the next and when depth is what I need, I need to stop. And if depth is not reached and the next `level` value does not exist, then raise some error.

Maybe there is some other way and approach to doing that?

Comment: You have a recursive structure.  Why would you *not* want to use recursion to deal with it?  It's well known that you *can*: recursion and iteration can always serve as replacements for one another.  But in this case, recursive code will be much cleaner.  For instance, `const byLevel = (obj, depth) => !obj ? undefined : depth == 0 ? obj : byLevel (obj .level, depth - 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the depth of the object, you might get a stack overflow. To be extra cautious, I'd just use a while-loop.

You could write a function to loop over the object every time you want to get the value at a depth. This is fine if you're running it once, however, this is inefficient if you need to call it multiple times because the time complexity is O(n).

Instead, I would flatten the object so you have a sort of look-up array. The flatten function's time complexity is O(n), but every subsequent lookup is O(1). Take a look at this code:

```js
function flatDepth(obj) {
  let res = [];
  while(typeof obj === 'object') {
    res.push(obj.value);
    obj = obj.level;
  }
  return res;
}

const obj = {
  "level": {
    "value": "one",
    "level": {
      "value": "two",
      "level": {
        "value": "three",
        "level": {
          "value": "four",
          "level": {
            "value": "five"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
const flattened = flatDepth(obj);
console.log(flattened);

console.log(flattened[3]); // => 3
console.log(flattened[0]); // => undefined
console.log(flattened[5]); // => undefined
```

Comment: Yeah, thats what i want. But I don't understand why first element is `undefined`. Can You explain?

Comment: @Dmiich The top object doesn't have a `.value` property, only `.level`,  therefore the value is undefined. If you want, you could add `value: 0` at the very top of the object.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value at a particular level without recursion like this:

```js
const obj = {
  "level": {
    "value": "one",
    "level": {
      "value": "two",
      "level": {
        "value": "three",
        "level": {
          "value": "four",
          "level": {
            "value": "five"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
const getValueAtLevel = level => {
  let p = obj.level;
  while(level-- > 1) p = p.level;
  return p.value;
}
console.log(getValueAtLevel(2));
```

Alternatively, you can flatten like this:

```js
const obj = {
  "level": {
    "value": "one",
    "level": {
      "value": "two",
      "level": {
        "value": "three",
        "level": {
          "value": "four",
          "level": {
            "value": "five"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
const flatten = obj => {
  let p = obj, r = [];
  while(p.level) { r.push(p.level.value); p = p.level; }
  return r;
}
console.log(flatten(obj));
```